# is "iwconfig" command need root android device?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface, root

i need to make iwconfig command on my android device, So i wrote c++ code and join it by ndk to have native method for that, this is my method :

```
jstring Java_com_example_ndk1_MainActivity_exec(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis , jstring cmd) {
const char * res;

jboolean isCopy;
res = env->GetStringUTFChars(cmd, &isCopy);

if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(cmd, res);
}

std::string result = exec(res);
return (env)->NewStringUTF((const char* )result.c_str());
}
```

but after doing that when i invoked this method and pass "iwconfig " , the application stopped and caused exception :

```
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):    ... 11 more
03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.ndk1.MainActivity.exec:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):   at com.example.ndk1.MainActivity.exec(Native Method)
 03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):   at  com.example.ndk1.MainActivity.command(MainActivity.java:34)
 03-03 00:07:15.674: E/AndroidRuntime(11872):   ... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you expecting `exec()` to return? (it generally doesn't)

Comment: yes it return string value

Comment: iwconfig is old, please use [iw](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw) - it is part of Android user space.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is "UnsatisfiedLinkError" - It means you are doing something wrong using JNI.

Did you compile your native library?Can you see it in lib\armeabi\?
Did you load the native library in the java code with 'System.loadLibrary'?

Beside this ofcourse you are making an assumption that iwconfig is actually a valid binary/command in Android linux, and I afraid in most cased iwconfig is not there.

About permissions, I think if you are going to peek in the interface list then you will have enough permissions. But if you will try to change something, it wont give you without root(Have you seen many applications that can connect you to wifi without your will?)

You can also execute commands with Java,Ex.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "\tmp"});

Because your java code and native code runs in the same permission context, it doesn't matter where you run it. Hope it helps.

Comment: regarding to library yes i can see it under libNDK1.so
and i follow this link to compile my lib http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: but do i need permissions in manifest file ?
how can i know if iwconfig is legal command for android ?

Comment: You try to execute the iwconfig command with 'adb' tool. You can use it to get shell(console) like in linux and try to execute it by just typing it. You can also try: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"iwconfig"});

Comment: Also, the permissions from AndroidManifest are enforced in the Java framework. In the linux userspace your uid will be random.

Comment: instead of call from android call the method by java,
sorry i don't know what is 'adb' ?

Comment: but this commands used to control device outside the application i need the application itself make this command ?